# Using location API to get weather details - BUG (REACT JS)

Tags: reactjs, api, weather

I'm only 13 years old, so please be nice.

I am currently trying to make a weather app that displays information based on a weather API, that gets information based on the user's location. If you must know, I am using the Open Weather api, and IPInfo for geolocation. If you need any further information to answer the question, please let me know.

```
async function getCity() {
    let response = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=MYTOKEN");
    let data = await response.json();
    let City = data.city;
    return String((City.replace(\/s/g, "")).toLowerCase()) // city name needs to be in all lower case no spaces for API url
}
async function getWeatherInfo() {
    let apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=imperial&q=" + getCity() + "&appid=MYAPIKEY";
    let weatherResponse = await fetch(apiUrl);
    let weatherData = await weatherResponse.json();
    console.log(weatherData.main.temp);
}
getWeatherInfo();
```

I was expecting the program to automatically get the user's city, and then get the weather information for that city. However, if just gives me errors:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, and you're only 13, so you should be proud you're on the right path.

Your getCity() is an async function, JS is synchronous.
When you call getCity() inside getWeatherInfo() to set 'apiURL', it's not going to return the value instantly, hence the undefined.

One way to go about this would be to set the city before you make the call to getWeatherInfo().

You can assign this to a variable, and then use that variable in the subsequent call.